# Creating an association between a source document and each item with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm building my first web application and am sort of lost. I've read the nokogiri docs, and know that I need to use `Nokogiri::XML(open("http://foo"))`, but I'm not sure where the proper place is to use it.

I have a `series` model with three columns, `:name`, `:description` and `:url`. I want to have it so when I create a new `series`, the URL placed in the `:url` form field is parsed, and creates an `episode` for each item in the feed, populating its columns with xpath arguments.

Would this logic go in the `series` model or controller? Or in the `episodes` model or controller?

Here's what I have now.

`series` model

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true
  has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`series` controller

```
class SeriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @series_all = Series.all
  end

  def show
    @series = Series.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @series = Series.new
  end

  def edit
    @series = Series.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @series = Series.new(series_params)

    if @series.save
      redirect_to @series
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @series = Series.find(params[:id])
    @series.destroy

    redirect_to series_path
  end

  private
    def series_params
      params.require(:series).permit(:name, :description, :url)
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :series do
    resources :episodes
  end
  root 'home#index'
end
```

`series` form partial

```
<%= form_for @series do |f| %>
  <div class="series-form">
    <div class="series-form__name">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="series-form__description">
      <%= f.label :description %>
      <%= f.text_area :description %>
    </div>

    <div class="series-form__url">
      <%= f.label :url %>
      <%= f.text_field :url %>
    </div>

    <div class="series-form__submit">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`episodes` has an empty controller with no model yet.

---

Edit: To clarify, I'm trying to import podcasts. So using The Stack Exchange Podcast's [RSS feed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/) as an example, I would place this in the `series` form:

Name: The Stack Exchange Podcast (from `channel/title`)

Description: Hosted by Joel Spolsky with Jay Hanlon and David Fullerton . . . (from `channel/itunes:summary`)

URL: `https://blog.stackoverflow.com/feed/podcast/`

and it would create an `episode` for each `item` in the feed. It would be even better if I could grab `channel/title` and `channel/itunes:summary` automatically. I hope this is possible and makes sense.

Comment: just to be clear, the series URL points to some web service that returns XML information about the series?  And what are the items in the feed?

Comment: @YevgeniyGoyfman Yes exactly. In my case it's podcasts, so it's RSS feeds, but AFAIK they're just xml. I edited my post to clarify a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need Nokogiri for this.  Just use the [RSS module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rss/rdoc/RSS.html) that comes with Ruby's standard lib.

As to your question, it looks like you want to populate the `ActiveRecord` model with the information from RSS feed.  The simplest way, especially if you are not planning to do this for any other data in your application, is to have controller make the call to RSS and map the data to the `Series` and `Episode` model there.  It would be cleaner (and easier to test) if you 
create special objects that can take the RSS data and generate `Series` from the channel data and `Episodes` from the item data.

The next step would be to treat RSS as another form of data storage (much like SQLite or MySQL databases), and create a layer of code that can interact with an RSS end-point and produce a mapped model (say `RSSSeries` and `RSSEpisodes` in your case) through an interface similar to `ActiveRecord` (but read-only, of course).  Controller then can be used to fetch the `RSSSeries` and access related `RSSEpisodes` translate it to the `ActiveRecord` `Series` and `Episodes` models and save them.

Comment: It looks like I have a lot to learn, haha. That RSS module looks promising. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Where would I create the special objects? I'd like to be capable of importing hundreds of podcasts potentially, does that change how I should approach this?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many, as long as they are represented by the same type of model.  In the case you are describing, I would create an `RssFeed` model object that doesn't inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`.  In `initialize` accept URL as the parameter and use the RSS module to fetch the feed.  Add methods to return the channel information (author, title, etc) and items.  Then in controller, map instance of `RssFeed` to `Series` and `Episodes`