# Is it possible to pass arguments from one controller, to create items of another?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails, and I've only created items through the standard `form_for` views interface. But I'd like to somehow make items through a controller. I have a `Subscription` model, which has one parameter, `:url`. When I create a `Subscription` item, I want it to delegate information to two other models, `Show` and `Episode`, based on the RSS content of that url.

Here's some pseudo-ish code of what I'm thinking the `Subscription` create method would look like:

```
def create
    require 'rss'
    require 'open-uri'

    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)

    if @subscription.save
        @show = Show.new
        @episode = Episode.new

        url = @subscription.url
        open(url) do |rss|
          feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
          @show.title = feed.channel.title
          feed.items.each do |item|
            @episode.title = item.title
            @episode.url = item.url
          end
        end

        redirect_to @subscription
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

I did the rails getting started guide, and it in they used `form_for([@article, @article.comments.build])` on a `has_many`/`belongs_to` association (which these 2 have). So I'm thinking I need to use `@subscription.show.build` and `@subscription.episode.build` somehow, but I don't know how exactly. I appreciate any help!

Comment: You're on the right track. Can you please elaborate on this statement: "I want it to delegate information to two other models"? Are `Shows` and `Episodes` associated with a `Subscription`?

Comment: @Alexander I just mean filling in the columns with xpath arguments, like `@show.title = feed.channel.title`. I was thinking of having them be unassociated from the `Subscription`, and just having the `Subscription` use `validates :url, uniqueness: true`. Really not sure if I'm going about this right, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach works just fine. `@subscription.show.build` and `@subscription.episode.build` are only useful and would work **IF** your `Subscription` model had the following associations:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  has_one :episode
  has_one :subscription

  ...
end
```

Since you don't want episodes or shows to be associated with a subscription, you shouldn't be using the `build` method. The Getting Started Guide used a nested form because `comments` are associated with `articles`. When creating a `comment`, the nested form would pass in the `id` of the `article` automatically, making it easier to create the association between `articles` and `comments`. So you don't need a nested form either.

I would make a few modifications to your code. You've created one `Episode` and are repeatedly changing its properties rather than creating multiple `Episodes`. Try this (I've commented the changed part of your code):

```
def create
    require 'rss'
    require 'open-uri'

    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)

    if @subscription.save
        @show = Show.new
        @episodes = []

        url = @subscription.url
        open(url) do |rss|
          feed = RSS::Parser.parse(rss)
          @show.title = feed.channel.title
          feed.items.each do |item|
            # ** START CHANGES **
            episode = Episode.new(title: item.title, url: item.url)
            @episodes.push(episode)
            # ** END CHANGES **
          end
        end

        redirect_to @subscription
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

One last thing I'd like to note is you're not saving your models. So after this controller action processes and you get redirected to the `Subscription` view, the shows and episodes won't be accessible if you leave the `Subscription` view. I'm not sure whether or not you wanted to save your models, but if you do want to save them, leave a comment, and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Honestly I just quickly threw it together, not knowing if it goes against best practices. So it is okay to create items of other controllers within a separate controller? I asked a similar question and the person who answered said I should do something that went way over my head. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603088/creating-an-association-between-a-source-document-and-each-item-with-nokogiri/34604364#34604364

Comment: "It would be cleaner (and easier to test) if you create special objects that can take the RSS data and generate Series from the channel data and Episodes from the item data." specifically

Comment: All he/she is saying is that you should create a separate class (not an `ActiveRecord` model) for getting and storing in memory the RSS feed data. So instead of getting all of the RSS feed data in your controller, you would spin it off into a separate class. This cleans up the code in the controller.

Comment: And to answer your latest question, yes it is fine to create items of other models in a given controller. A controller is basically the logic part of your application, while the View and the Model are the UI and the data, respectively.