# How do I place instances on a page without access to params in my create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, feedzirra, feedjira

I have three models, `Subscription`, `Show`, and `Episode`. `Subscription`'s role is to parse the feed in its `:url` column and instantiate `Show` and `Episode`, filling their columns with Feedjira properties.

I'm only able to access the episodes when I go to `shows/1/episodes/1`, using `<%= render @show.episodes %>` in the `Shows` show view doesn't work and doesn't give any errors.

In the Rails getting started guide, they used this as their `Comment` create method, which allowed for that.

```
@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
@comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
redirect_to article_path(@article)
```

Is it the lack of params that's causing this? If so, how would I use params in this method?

```
def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
        @show = Show.new
        @episodes = []

        # Feed
        @feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse @subscription.url

        # Show
        @show.title = @feed.title
        @show.description = @feed.description
        @show.genre = @feed.itunes_categories
        @show.url = @feed.url
        @show.logo = @feed.itunes_image

        @show.save

        # Episode
        @feed.entries.each do |item|
            @episodes.push(item)
        end

        @episodes.each do |item|
            @episode = @show.episodes.create

            @episode.title = item.title
            @episode.description = item.summary
            @episode.release_date = item.published
            @episode.show_id = @show

            @episode.save
        end
        redirect_to @subscription
    end
end
```

`episodes/_episode.hmtl.erb`

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <%= episode.title %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= episode.description %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= episode.url %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= episode.release_date %>
    </li>
    <li>
        <%= episode.show_id %>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`shows/show.html.erb`

```
<h1>Showing Show</h1>

<h2><%= @show.title %></h2>

<%= render @show.episodes %>
```

---

Adding my routes and models in case that's the issue:

`routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :shows do
    resources :episodes
  end
  resources :subscriptions
  root 'subscriptions#index'
end
```

`show.rb`

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

`episode.rb`

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
end
```

`subscription.rb`

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :url, uniqueness: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to just change

```
<%= render @show.episodes %>
```

to

```
<%= render partial: "episodes/episode", collection: @show.episodes %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#partials

And small advice: don't place your logic in controller.

Comment: That doesn't work either unfortunately. In the getting started guide they only used `<%= render @article.comments %>`, what enables that capability? RE: logic in my controller, I got the opposite advice the other day. I'm new to programming so I have no idea who to believe... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34701029/5741622